# Trusted data from c# rich app

Tags: c#, vb.net, certificate

Is there a way to create a C# application and a Server side API where the server side API will only allow data from the C# app?

The problem with .Net apps is you can decompile them and then recompile to make them send different data than what you are expecting. In my case the data is not secret, only the ability to write the data to the server side API is the trust issue.

What if I want the application to report back to the server if a certain hot fix is presently installed and then make a server side decision on that info? If an insider threat recompiles the code and modifies it to report false info then the data cannot be trusted. If only the un-modified application can communicate with the API then the data can be trusted and decisions can be made upon it.Can the application use the digital signature it gets signed with to perform a trusted hand shake to the server API?

Any ideas or conversation on the subject may prove helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, virtually nothing is "hackproof".  Security is a game of cat and mouse.

That said I would suggest [SslStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=netframework-4.7.1). Fairly easy to use.

It's .NET's implemention of SSL (Secure Sockets Layer), which is used in combination with `HTTP` very commonly seen as `HTTPS` all over the web.